# use psexec.exe in a powershell

Tags: invoke, psexec

im trying to use psexec.exe in powershell, but appear connect but do not nothing. Supposedly i call psexec in his route in my computer, with the parameters i usually use in a normal CMD.

```
C:\c\PsExec.exe \\Hostname.domain.CORP -u domain\admx097168 -p Password cmd -c “c:\temp\hola.vbs”
```

This is the response on the console.

```
PS C:\Users\x097168> C:\Consola\testmasiveSCCM.ps1
C:\c\PsExec.exe : 
En C:\Consola\testmasiveSCCM.ps1: 2 Carácter: 1
+ C:\c\PsExec.exe \\Hostname.domain.CORP -u domain\admx097 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.
```

appear still working, but do nothing, will be necessary stopped the scripting to continue.

Anyone can help me? first of all, thank you very much for reading my query.

one last thing, i can't use invoke-command, cause is forbidden in my domain.

Comment: First run of psexec (or any sysinternals tool) pops-up with a license messagebox which requires you to approve it (click 'OK'). Seems to me that it waits for it in a hidden session

Comment: hi yorammi, thanks for your response. When i execute the script first time, is true asking me for the permissions and licence, but once i accept it, the script appear in the status i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at finally i can do it with the next secuence.

C:\c\PsExec.exe \xxx.xx.xx.xxx -u prbes\admx000000 -p Pasw0rd -i -d cscript.exe c:\temp\test.vbs